# how to set content-type in http response when i don't know the type of image

Tags: http

I have a collection of images to be served, but they are of different types and doesn't have suffix, just a hash name.

What's a good way to set the content-type in http return to make sure there is no issues?

Can I use something like 'content-type=image/*' or something?

Answer (score -1):

Just don't set the content-type header field.

Comment: hmmm, does this work for all browsers/apps etc? it seems to cause a download file action on ie...